# Sorting lines in nano?

Tags: sort, nano

Is it possible to sort a selected area of text alphabetically using the nano editor?

( similar to the F10 in xed )

I use Linux Mint 20 , nano 4.8

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nano cannot do that. The best way to get this done is by learning the basics of file manipulation with the command line to chop the file in pieces, sort the piece you want to sort and put everything back together.

If you want to have a editor that can do everything, even run shell scripts on your file from within the editor, you should have a look at VIM for instance.

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.nano-editor.org/news.php:

> GNU nano 2.9.8 "Espresso" brings the ability to filter the buffer (or
> the marked region) through an external command (^R^X and prefix the
> command with the pipe symbol, "|").

so in *your* version (4.8), that would be:

1. Select the area that you want "line-wise" sorted (`M-A` i.e. `Alt`+`A` to start the selection). Note: select whole lines to keep this procedure sane!
2. Type "`^R^X`"  (that's `Ctrl`+`R`, `Ctrl`+`X`) to get the "`Command to execute`" prompt,
3. Enter "`|sort`" (without the double-quotes!)
4. (Optional) If you don't like the result, "`Undo`" using `M-U` (`Alt`+`U`).

In version 5.0 (released 2020-07-29), "`Execute Command`" was moved to the main menu (with `^T`, replacing the Spell Checker), so for me it's `<select lines>`, `Ctrl+T`, enter "`|sort`".